# NET MAUI how to check if GPS is enabled or force enable

Tags: .net, maui, android-gps

I need the gps to be enabled while using the app.
Can I force the gps to be enabled, or can I check somehow is it enabled.

thnx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the **location API** in **.NET MAUI** apps you have to gain permission from the users.

Luckily .NET MAUI abstracts as many permissions in the `Permissions` class as possible but due to the different OS some platforms might not be supported. And `Permissions` class offers two types of permissions to use **location API**:

- LocationWhenInUse
- LocationAlways

To gain permission to any API follow the procedure:

1. Check the permission status
2. Ask for the permission if needed

### Checking permission

Before you try to use an API check whether the app is granted permission to use the API or not. The following Code snippet demonstrates how to check the permission status for location (Check the documentation for more permissions)

```csharp
PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

If the permission status is `granted` then it is safe to use the API otherwise you have to ask for the permission as demonstrated in the next section.

### Request permissions

If the permission is not granted yet it is possible to ask for permission from the user using the following code snippet (Again check the documentation for more permissions)

```csharp
PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

#### Summary

To summarize you have to request permission from the user to use some APIs including the location API, and always check the permission status before using the API to ensure smooth UX and avoid any weird behaviours.

#### Helpful Links

[Learn more about Permissions in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=android)

[A list of the available permissions with the supported operating systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=android#available-permissions)

[Permission class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.applicationmodel.permissions?view=net-maui-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't force enable the android gps service programmatically. The official document about [Changing location settings](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings) said:

> If your app needs to request location or receive permission updates, the device needs to enable the appropriate system settings, such as GPS or Wi-Fi scanning. Rather than directly enabling services such as the device's GPS, your app specifies the required level of accuracy/power consumption and desired update interval, and the device automatically makes the appropriate changes to system settings.

But you can check if GPS is enabled and then go to the android location settings page to let the user turn it on.

```
var lm = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.LocationService) as Android.Locations.LocationManager;
var isenabled = lm.IsProviderEnabled(Android.Locations.LocationManager.GpsProvider);
// check if GPS is enabled
if(isenabled==false)
{
   Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings));
   //go to the android location settings page
}
```